Subtract date from database with current date in datatables
I have a date stored in database in YYYY-MM-DD format. I want to subtract the date with current date to calculate difference in years.
My code looks like this:
<table id="my_table">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>DOB</th>
<th>Age</th>
</table>

Script
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                let table = $("#my_table").DataTable({                   
                    ajax: "{{route('my_table')}}",           
                    columns: [
                        {data:'Name',name:'Name',orderable:false},                     
                        {data:'DOB',name:'DOB',orderable:false},
                        {data:null,title : 'days', 
render: function ( data, type, row ) { 
  var dbdate = moment(data.DOB, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
  var now = moment();
  return now.diff(dbdate, 'Age'); 
}},

                    ]                 
                });
            });
        </script>

(I looked into this link but my datatable won't load if the calculation code is implemented.)

Never mind, tested some codes and found the result.
{data:null, 
   render: function (data, type, row, meta){
       const date=new Date();
       let date2=new Date(row.DOB_E);
       return Math.floor((date-date2)/(365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
}

